# Install & configuring Kafka connect in google cloud

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I had installed Kafka in google cloud and need help to install and configure Kafka connect in google cloud.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are currently simply expecting us to solve the problem **for you**. **PLEASE** Give it a try **on your own**, and then show us what you came up with - and if you get stuck along the way, feel free to come back and ask for help.

Comment: Atleast can you provide a reference document to follow the steps to create kafka connect?